# Akismet being too harsh?

Tags: spam-prevention, akismet

I'm using Akismet for my spam protection on my web page. It won't even let users post something like, "Hey guys check this out!". I was hoping that I could just get rid of links and have them check the posters IP to see if it had been logged, but not block something so simple.

Is there a way to decrease the harshness through Akismet? I'm using the .NET 2.0 library here http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=AkismetApi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest not using Akismet at all and just managing it yourself. You could write a regex to remove the links from postings: http://www.jhartig.com/2010/02/perfect-regex-for-removing-links-when.html

Instead of using one of these anti-spam engines, have you thought about using Facebook the way TechCrunch does? It is very effectively at not allowing spam or flamewars because it's not anonymous.

The other things to use is ReCaptcha, to keep the bots out which is probably the cause of your spam problems in the first place.  http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: Can you use recaptcha without using forms though?

Comment: If someone is posting something, they're probably using a form.  I'm not sure how you would do it without a form, but I'm not sure what you'd do with it outside of a form.

Comment: There's just a single textbox with a submit button

Comment: That's all you need for a form, one form element and a way to submit it.

Comment: But what I mean is, it's not an HTML form, and I'd rather not make it one.

Answer (score 4):

For questions about Akismet you are always welcome to drop us a line - http://akismet.com/contact/

For cases like this the first thing I suggest is making sure that you are sending the correct data for the Akismet API call - http://akismet.com/development/api/#comment-check - since sending wrong or insufficient data can reduce the accuracy.

Second, if Akismet makes a mistake you should be sending the data back via the Submit Ham and Submit Spam API calls.  This allows the Akismet system to learn more about what you consider spam/not spam on your site.

Answer (score 1):

hey here are my two cents to the topic:
try something that webcrawlers hate!! something they can't understand at ALL!!
you guessed it right pal!! FLASH!!

If I were you would use something flash like: [flexi commment](http://flexicommentbox.alimsyed.com/) or something